# Page views and Visits using traffic variables in Sitecatalyst

Tags: javascript, web, web-analytics, adobe-analytics

We are using omniture sitecatalyst analytics tool  to find

1)Page views by User

2)Visits by User.

I have achieved first requirement using below approach

1)**Page views by User:** Just I need to find page views by user.To achieve this,I have declared following Predefined /Custom traffic variables in each page name and have defined and enabled traffic variable USERID in Admin section.

```
s.account=s_account
s.channel=channelname
s.pagename=page1

//custom trafic variable for userid
s.prorp3=loginid
```

I  have navigated to CUSTOM TRAFFIC->CUSTOM TRAFFIC 1-10->  selected **USERID** and it showed me all user's and page views.

**USERID               Page Views**

user1                    100

user2                    200

user3                    300

If I click on break down icon of each user and can see page views viewed by each user.

**user1:**:

**Page Names                  Instances**

page1                       10

page2                       20

2)Now I need to find how many visits made by each user.

I have navigated to each menu in sitecatalyst and can't find anything related visits in reports section.Please let me know where/how can I find Visit Report and looking for a report similar to below

**Ex:**

USERID          VISITS

user1              10

user2              4

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

visits is a metric.  In the report you used for #1, at the top right of the part of the report that shows your columns and data, there's an "add metrics" button.  Click on that and drag "visits" from the list of metrics to add it to your report.

sidenote: an eVar set to visit expiration will likely be more useful to you, especially when you want to start figuring out more complex things.

page views is how many times the dimension was popped (or persisted on, like an eVar rolling over based on expiration) a page view request (an s.t call). instances is how many times the dimension was popped on all requests (page view s.t and custom link tracking s.tl)

**edit:** from your followup question below...

**pageview vs. instance metric**

`page views` is how many times the dimension was popped (or persisted on, like an eVar rolling over based on expiration) a page view request (an `s.t` call). `instances` is how many times the dimension was popped on *all* requests (page view `s.t` and custom link tracking `s.tl`).

Consider the following code:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<a onclick="s_trackThis();">click me!</a>

<script  type='text/javascript'>
function s_trackThis() {
  s.linkTrackVars='prop1';
  s.prop1='foobar';
  s.tl(true,'o','link click');
}
</script>

<!--simplified on-page global code-->
<script  type='text/javascript'>var s_account='somersid';</script>
<script  type='text/javascript' scr='s_account.js'></script>
<script  type='text/javascript'>
s.pageName = 'some page';
s.prop1 = 'foobar';
s.t();
</script>
<!--end simplifed on-page global code-->
</body>
</html>
```

On first page load, the on-page code is triggered, and `prop1` is recorded with a value of "foobar".  So that's one page view and one instance hit.  Then, when you click on the link, the wrapper function is invoked and `prop1` is popped again with the same value. The function makes a `s.tl` call which does not count as a page view, so now you will see 2 `instances` and 1 `pageview` for the value "foobar"

Comment: Thank you.I am able to see visits by user by adding "visits" to metrics.I have one more question what is the difference between instances and page views ?

Comment: `page views` is how many times the dimension was popped (or persisted on, like an eVar rolling over based on expiration) a page view request (an `s.t` call). `instances` is how many times the dimension was popped on *all* requests (page view `s.t` and custom link tracking `s.tl`).

Comment: In my experience, the `instances` metric is useful for QAing an implementation, but it isn't really useful for reporting purposes.