# Page views and Visits using conversion variable in Sitecatalyst

Tags: javascript, web, web-analytics, adobe-analytics

With reference to this question [Page views and Visits using traffic variables in Sitecatalyst](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17721924/page-views-and-visits-using-traffic-variables-in-sitecatalyst) I have changed USERID from traffic variable to conversion variable (evar).

I have navigated to CUSTOM CONVERSION->CUSTOM CONVERSION 1-10-> selected USERID and it showed me all user's and Visits.

```
USERID  VISITS

user1    3

user2    4

user3    20
```

I just dragged "Page views" from "add metrics" button and can see below report

```
USERID  VISITS  PAGE VIEWS 

user1    3       20

user2    4       40

user3    2       10
```

If I click on break down icon of user1 and have following report,I have noticed that Visit value changes for each page,my understanding is it should be same for all pages ie 3 int this case.Please let me know the reason.

```
          Visits        Page Views

user1:         3              20


home           3               4  

login          3               4

about          2               4

details        1               4

registration   1               4
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that breakdown report, you are seeing the pages that contributed to each of user1's 3 visits.

- All three visits touched the home page at one time.
- Two of the three visits viewed the about page.
- Only one of the three visits touched the registration page.